# Chart.js Angular error with data from .json file

Tags: angular, chart.js

I have a simple array of data, that I want to display in a chart using the chart.js library. The only error occurring seems to be with some DeepPartialObjects referring to some issues in the chart options with y and x axes. I am both new to Angular and Chart.js, and been struggling with solving this issue.

My current code looks like this:

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js/auto';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Fruit } from './fruit.model';
import { FruitService } from './fruit.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'angular-fetch-json-data';
    public fruits: Fruit[];
    public chart: any;

    public constructor(private fruitService: FruitService) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.fruitService.getFruits().subscribe((response) => {
            this.fruits = response.fruits;
            this.createChart();
        })
    }

    createChart() {
        if (this.chart) {
            this.chart.destroy();
        }

        // Extract the labels and data from the fruits array
        const labels = this.fruits.map((fruit: any) => fruit.fruit);
        const data = this.fruits.map((fruit: any) => fruit.amountBought);

        this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        data: data,
                        borderColor: '#3cba9f',
                        fill: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: data,
                        borderColor: '#ffcc00',
                        fill: false
                    },
                ]
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
data.json file:

   

     {
        "fruits": [
            {
                "fruit": "Apple",
                "size": "Large",
                "color": "Red",
                "amountBought": 100
            },
        
            {
                "fruit": "Banana",
                "size": "Small",
                "color": "Yellow",
                "amountBought": 76
            },
            {
                "fruit": "Strawberry",
                "size": "Medium",
                "color": "Red",
                "amountBought": 732
            },
            {
                "fruit": "Blueberry",
                "size": "Small",
                "color": "Blue",
                "amountBought": 27
            }
        ]
        }

The issues are with Yaxes and xAxes, at least according to the compiler. I've tried numerous things with those, and also changing different stuff with the chart options, but can't seem to figure it out.
```

Comment: Can you attach the sample data?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create the chart before the data is fetched from the server. You should move the createChart() method call inside the subscribe callback, so it's called after the data is fetched and assigned to the fruits variable

Comment: @YongShun
Sample data here:

{
"fruits": [
    {
        "fruit": "Apple",
        "size": "Large",
        "color": "Red",
        "amountBought": 100
    },

    {
        "fruit": "Banana",
        "size": "Small",
        "color": "Yellow",
        "amountBought": 76
    },
    {
        "fruit": "Strawberry",
        "size": "Medium",
        "color": "Red",
        "amountBought": 732
    },
    {
        "fruit": "Blueberry",
        "size": "Small",
        "color": "Blue",
        "amountBought": 27
    }
]
}

Comment: @Stefan but I am calling it after the data is fetched, no?

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fruitService.getFruits().subscribe((response) => {
      this.fruits = response.fruits;
    })
    this.createChart();
  }

Comment: @NewProgrammer1500 you are indeed calling this.createChart() within ngOnInit(), but it is not inside the subscribe() callback, which means that it's called before the data is fetched and assigned to the fruits variable. To fix this issue, you should move the this.createChart(); method call inside the subscribe() callback

Comment: Thanks @Stefan! I did but it did not fix the errors in the compiler, but cheers I understand your point now!

Comment: Yes, because you need to update your chart options to match the newer Chart.js configuration. This should resolve the issues related to xAxes and yAxes

Comment: I updated the code in the thread now. It is still throwing the same two errors with deep partial objects - cheers for the assistance thus far.

Answer (score 0):

**Concern 1**

As mentioned by @Stefan, move the `this.createChart()` in the `subscribe()` callback as the observable is asynchronous. By moving into the callback, it will guarantee the `this.createChart()` will be executed when the observable is returned.

```js
this.fruitService.getFruits().subscribe((response) => {
  this.fruits = response.fruits;

  this.createChart();
});
```

**Concern 2**

I believe that you install *chart.js* with version 3 or later, which is incompatible with your current Chart.js configuration. From the documentation, [xAxes and yAxes are no longer supported](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v3-migration.html#scales). Follow the instruction for the migration:

- The `xAxes` and `yAxes` arrays were removed and axis options are individual scales now keyed by scale ID
- `legend`, `title` and `tooltip` namespaces were moved from `options` to `options.plugins`

And to render the chart from the component (back-code), you should work with `@ViewChild` decorator.

Your code should be as below:

> Component

```js
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';

@ViewChild('baseChart', { static: true })
  canvasElem: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  createChart() {
    if (this.chart) {
      this.chart.destroy();
    }

    // Extract the labels and data from the fruits array
    const labels = this.fruits.map((fruit: any) => fruit.fruit);
    const data = this.fruits.map((fruit: any) => fruit.amountBought);

    const ctx = this.chart.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            data: data,
            borderColor: '#3cba9f',
            fill: false,
          },
          {
            data: data,
            borderColor: '#ffcc00',
            fill: false,
          },
        ],
      },

      options: {
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
        scales: {
          x: {
            display: true,
          },

          y: {
            display: true,
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
            },
          },
        },
      } as ChartOptions<'line'>,
    });
  }
```

> HTML

```
<canvas #baseChart class="chart"></canvas>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvxbtl?file=src/main.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I made the code work with help from you guys! Thank you so much!
Here is the working code:

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js/auto';

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Fruit } from './fruit.model';
import { FruitService } from './fruit.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'angular-fetch-json-data';
  public fruits: Fruit[];
  public chart: any;

  public constructor(private fruitService: FruitService){
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fruitService.getFruits().subscribe((response) => {
      this.fruits = response.fruits;
      this.createChart();
    })
  }

  createChart() {
    if (this.chart) {
      this.chart.destroy();
    }

    // Extract the labels and data from the fruits array
    const labels = this.fruits.map((fruit: any) => fruit.fruit);
    const data = this.fruits.map((fruit: any) => fruit.amountBought);

    
    this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
      type: 'line', 
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            data: data,
            borderColor: '#3cba9f', 
            fill: false 
          },
        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: {
            display: true
          },
          yAxes: {
            display: true,
              beginAtZero: true
            
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```